# Sharepoint 2010 dropdown menu on mobile

Tags: asp.net, css, drop-down-menu, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a hovering dropdown menu in Sharepoint 2010 that works fine with a mouse, but what I'm also trying to achieve is getting the menu to not reload the page on a mobile device (since the user has to click on menu dropdown) and act more like a `onHover`, I tried removing the `href` for the menu but that didn't do anything. I also compared my app to others made with sharepoint that work well on mobile, and i can't really see what they are doing different

is it some kind of css I'm missing? if you've run into this before I'd really appreciate your help.

here are the properties set in the asp menu:

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu
  ID="TopNavigationMenuV4"
  Runat="server"
  EnableViewState="false"
  DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
  AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
  UseSimpleRendering="true"
  UseSeparateCss="false"
  Orientation="Horizontal"
  StaticDisplayLevels="1"
  MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
  SkipLinkText=""
  CssClass="s4-tn"/>
```

and this is the html that is generated when i view the source:

```
 <li class="static dynamic-children selected"><br>
 <a class="static dynamic-children selected menu-item" title="Home" href="/sites/Test/Pages/default.aspx" accesskey="1">
 <span class="additional-background"><br>
 <span class="menu-item-text"><br>
 Test <br>
 </span>
```

Comment: You need to flesh out your question with some code. There isn't enough for anybody to be able to help you and your question is too vague.

Comment: i added the asp menu code that's in sharepoint designer. im not sure how helpful that may be though, most of this stuff was auto generated

Comment: i also added the html when i view the source, but didnt realize the guidline for adding html here, it doesnt look right now, but am working on fixing that

Comment: Perhaps you could share the css that is on these items and a bit more html showing the parent and children menu items.

Comment: seems like my problem was fixed by having the href call a function that returns null when clicked on

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really obvious. But i can tell you this. If you don't want anything to happen you can use

```
onclick="return false;"
```